# Is the PartialFunction design inefficient?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8

This is something I've wondered about for a while. I see this pattern a lot:

```
if (pf.isDefinedAt(in)) pf(in)
```

By breaking this up into two separate calls, all of the patterns that were evaluated in #isDefinedAt are then also evaluated in #apply.  For example:

```
object Ex1 {
  def unapply(in: Int) : Option[String] = {
    println("Ex1")
    if (in == 1) Some("1") else None
  }
}

object Ex2 {
  def unapply(in: Int) : Option[String] = {
    println("Ex2")
    if (in == 2) Some("2") else None
  }
}

val pf : PartialFunction[Int,String] = {
  case Ex1(result) => result
  case Ex2(result) => result
}

val in = 2

if (pf.isDefinedAt(in)) pf(in)
```

Which prints

```
Ex1
Ex2
Ex1
Ex2
res52: Any = 2
```

In the worst case, where your pattern matches last, you've evaluated your patterns/extractors twice when calling a PartialFunction. This could become inefficient when matching over custom extractors that did more than just a simple class or list pattern match (for example, if you had an extractor that parsed an XML document and returned some value objects)

PartialFunction#lift suffers from the same double-evaluation:

```
scala> pf.lift(2)
Ex1
Ex2
Ex1
Ex2
res55: Option[String] = Some(2)
```

Is there a way to conditionally call a function if it is defined without potentially calling all of your extractors twice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [a conversation going on about this](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/4030/match=functionwithdefault) *right now* on the **scala-internals** mailing list. Martin Odersky has suggested a new type: `FunctionWithDefault`. Martin talks not only of a run-time penalty, but a compile time penalty (of class file bloat) of using `PartialFunction`:

> First, we need to generate the pattern matching code twice, once in the apply and then again in the isDefinedAt. Second, we also need to execute the code twice, first to test whether the function is applicable, and then to actually apply it.

The answer to your question is essentially "yes" and and this behaviour (of `PartialFunction`) will not change either due to backwards-compatibility issues (for example, what if the `isDefinedAt` is side-effecting).

The new type being proposed, `FunctionWithDefault` has no `isDefinedAt` and has a method:

```
trait FunctionWithDefault[-I, +O] {
  def applyOrElse[OO >: O](i : I, default : I => OO) : OO
}
```

which acts a bit like `Option`s `getOrElse` method.

I have to say that, as usual, I cannot imagine this inefficiency poses any sort of performance *problem* in the overwhelming majority of cases.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! FunctionWithDefault sounds like just what I was looking for.

Comment: Pattern matching twice definitely is a big performance hit if you have complex match statements in performance-critical code!  And if `default` is passed by name, how is this supposed to be more efficient than returning an option?  Maybe I should be reading scala-internals.

Comment: I've got the sig of default wrong, rather bizarrely it's an `I => OO`

Comment: Current Scala compiler generates `getOrElse` for `PartialFunction` literals. I think we should always use that method and should never call `isDefined` manually. For `PartialFunction` in a pattern matching, consider converting it to an extractor: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/g0-hbN5qerQ